# Contact Form 7 Shortcode to Array

Tags: php

```
$contact_form_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'contact-form-data', true );
$contact_explode = explode(" ",$contact_form_value);
var_dump($contact_explode);
```

`$contact_form_value` is equals to this `[contact-form-7 id="105" title="BusinessAssistance"]` using the code above gives me the wrong answer..

how to convert that to array? I need the id and the title

Comment: What did you already try? Looks like a job for a regular expression.

Comment: i try explode but it gives me the wrong output

Comment: `echo $contact_form_value['title'];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$contact_form_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'contact-form-data', true );
$regex = '/\[contact-form-7\s+id=[\'|"](\d+)[\'|"]\s+title=[\'|"](.+)[\'|"]\]/';
if (preg_match($regex, $contact_form_value, $matches)) {
    $id = $matches[1];
    $title = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: Hi,please try again - it was some mistake in regular expression during pasting it on stackoverflow.